# How are the bits arranged in int8_t

Tags: c++, c

The signed `int8_t` type is less intuitive than `uint8_t`.

For example: `-36` decimal is coded `11011100` binary (`220` decimal if read unsigned)

In other words how to **manually** convert from int8_t to its absolute value?

> *Sometimes the easy things are not so easy found*

---

EDIT

How are the bits arranged in int8_t?
I want to understand the int8_t and the steps to get its absolute value

Comment: Why are you posting a question and then immediately answering it yourself?

Comment: @Sean: Why not? [This is encouraged.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) In fact it's _so_ encouraged that there's literally a feature to do that on the Ask Question page... Did you perhaps forget that Stack Overflow is a Q&A repository for general use, not a personal helpdesk?

Comment: @Sean [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @Sean What difference does it make if OP answers it or someone else?

Comment: @Sean Because it took me some time to find the answer. It may be useful for others

Comment: What do you mean by "manually"?

Comment: That being said, I don't really understand the question/problem. Is this asking how to comprehend two's complement representation? Or how to cast a `int8_t` to some other type? Or what? Reading the OP's answer leaves me none the wiser.

Comment: What do you mean by _"the steps to get its absolute value"_? You already have its "absolute value", right there. Unless you mean mathematically, i.e. 36? So just `* -1`? You do not need to know anything about the representation or the bits... that's exactly why we have a nice high level language to do it for you.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, if you apply `* -1` to `std::uint8_t`, you'll get a value of another type.

Comment: The best way to get the absolute value is something like this: `int8_t x = -3; uint8_t y = abs(x);`

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Thanks for helping me getting better in writing questions. I mean that I want to understand *two's complement representation* but without knowing its name.

Comment: @klutt Yes, that's a good way :) but I wanted to understand how it works

Comment: @Evg Just as you will with any of the bitwise operations.

Comment: @Guglie, you might want to take a look at the generated [assembly code](https://godbolt.org/z/AUaoer).

Comment: @Evg Thanks! Surely that's useful even if I was searching for something more like the int8_t spec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [C99 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) used as reference from C+11:

> 7.18.1.1 Exact-width integer types
>   The typedef name **`intN_t`** designates a signed integer type with width N, no padding bits, and a
>   **two’s complement representation**. Thus, int8_t denotes a signed integer
>   type with a width of exactly 8 bits.

From Wikipedia [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement):

> The two's complement of an N-bit number is defined as its complement
>   with respect to 2N. For instance, for the three-bit number 010, the
>   two's complement is 110, because 010 + 110 = 1000. **The two's
>   complement is calculated by inverting the digits and adding one.**

So from the above example (signed to absolute)

```
(-36 decimal) = 11011100

(inverting)  -> 00100011

(+1)         -> 00100100

              = (36 decimal)
```

-36 decimal to int8_t

```
(36 decimal) = 00100100

(-1)        -> 00100011

(invert)    -> 11011100

            = (-36 decimal)
```

Comment: Note that for signed integer types other than the fixed width `intN_t` types, in C as well as C++ (until C++20), the sign representation depends on implementation, and could in theory be other than 2's complement. That said, non 2's complement hardware is becoming quite rare these days.

Comment: @eerorika Does that mean that on a platform with 32 bit `int` that isn't two's complement, the type `int` and `int32_t` are different types?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Such platform probably wouldn't define any of `intN_t`. The fixed width type aliases are optional. If it did define it, then it would have to be different from a type that isn't 2's complement.

Comment: I'm curious why this answer has so many downvotes. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @eerorika thanks for the clarification! By the way I was searching only for fixed width integer types :)

Comment: This is a very roundabout way of multiplying by -1 or using `std::abs`. Just get the language & compiler to do it for you; that's literally why we have them. You do not need to know anything about the representation or the bits.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Thanks, I didn't mean to reinvent the wheel. Surely there are a lot of wonderful tools that do the job for us, but **sometimes it's enlightening to understand how they work**. Sometimes not knowing what's under the hood leads even to problems like *Leaky Abstraction*

Comment: @Guglie Absolutely - and if you'd phrased your question like that, it would have been understood that way ;)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Some people have problems with people self answering their questions.